# How to visualize all the lines in instance.display() using Pyomo

Tags: model, output, instance, display, pyomo

I am working with Pyomo and after solving the model, I use instance.display() to visualize the outputs, however this message appears: "Se han truncado las últimas 5000 líneas del flujo de salida." or in English "The last 5000 lines of the output stream have been truncated".

How could I fix this and see all the outputs?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a filename to the `display` method to output the text to a file.

```
 instance.display('myfile.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks, and how could I download the file? I am using Google Colab